# Laravel create/save a model with multiple relations

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

I have 3 tables. 2 of them belong to 1 table.

```
company:
    id
    company_info (FK to the id of company_infos)
    address (FK to to the id of addresses)

company_info:
    id
    company_name
    owner

address:
    id
    country
    street 
    number
```

My relations in the company model:

```
public function address(){
        return $this->hasOne(Address::class, $this->primaryKey, 'address');
    }

    public function company_info(){
        return $this->hasOne(CompanyInfo::class, $this->primaryKey, 'company_info');
    }
```

(My relations do work; I can get the company with their relations in my get request.)

The only way I can think of create a new company is to create `company_info` and `address` first and pass their id's to create a new `company`.

How do I create those 2 models so that the `company` model gets those 2 models' ids by their relations?

So when I send the data from my front end to Laravel like this to create a new company, how would I make a new company based on this data that's going to fill the other 2 models?

```
"company_info": {
    "company_name": "aCompany",
    "owner": "someone"
},
"address": {
    "country": "some_country",
    "street": "some_street",
    "number": 123
}
```

Comment: Your 2 last paragraphs are extremely unclear.

Comment: @philipxy so what I am trying to say is, when I want to create a new company. I have to pass 2 integers. But I am getting instead of 2 integers an object/model. So I know when I get those objects I can create them, get their id's and then create a company based on that. But their has to be a way that I can create it with relations instead of doing it manually. Hope you understand me know a bit

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

You would first need to create the `company_info` and the `address` data via their models (There is many ways to create a instance of the model this is just the way I prefer, other alternatives include using the new keyword then saving etc.. etc...) like:

```php
$address = Address::create([
// Attributes
]);

// and
$companyInfo = CompanyInfo::create([
// Attributes
]);
```

which would then have the 2 pieces of data required for creating the `Company` which can be done the same way as above but set the keys to the respective `$address->id` and `$companyInfo->id`

Ex.

```php
Company::create([
// Attributes
]);
```

If you need any more clarification I am more than willing to elaborate further.